# I have many elseif statements. How can i optimize them?

Tags: php

Is there any way to optimize this code? I mean its working and all but it seems with lots of "elseif" its actually not so optimized:

```php
foreach ($plenty_variation['properties'] as $row) {
    
    if (strpos($row['relationValues']['0']['value'], $needle_de_0) === 0) {
        $result_de_0 = $row['relationValues']['0']['value'];
        $shopware["translations"]["0"]["customFields"]["free1"] = str_replace("Text_de_0_","",$result_de_0);
        break;
    }
    elseif (strpos($row['relationValues']['1']['value'], $needle_de_0) === 0) {
        $result_de_0 = $row['relationValues']['1']['value'];
        $shopware["translations"]["0"]["customFields"]["free1"] = str_replace("Text_de_0_","",$result_de_0);
        break;
    }
    elseif (strpos($row['relationValues']['2']['value'], $needle_de_0) === 0) {
        $result_de_0 = $row['relationValues']['2']['value'];
        $shopware["translations"]["0"]["customFields"]["free1"] = str_replace("Text_de_0_","",$result_de_0);
        break;
    }
}
```

In `$row['relationValues']['0']['value']` the `['0']` is inconsistent and not always the same.

Comment: Can you just `foreach` over `$row['relationValues']`?

Comment: If max interval is known maybe https://3v4l.org/FSjcJ

Comment: It can be from 0 to (max i have seen) 100. But anyway would that be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use another loop?

```
foreach ($plenty_variation['properties'] as $row) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++){
       $value = $row['relationValues'][$i]['value'];
       if(strpos($value, $needle_de_0) === 0){
           $shopware["translations"][$i]["customFields"]["free" . $i] = str_replace("Text_de_0_", "", $value);
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

In the case above I take that you'd like to loop the $shopware['translations'] positions as the same of the $plenty_variation['properties']. If this is not the case, just let it fixed:

```
$shopware["translations"]["0"]["customFields"]["free1"]
```